# Virtualization issue when using EVE-NG VM in VMWARE: neither Intel VT-x or AMD-V found

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to use the EVE-NG virtual machine that uses Ubuntu 16 in VMWare Player 16 using Windows 10 Home. But I have the problem that when starting the machine the following message is displayed:

**Warning: neither Intel VT-x or AMD-V found.**

[Warning VMWARE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYTVm.jpg)

I want to add that this happened after enabling WSL2, searching I read that WSL2 and Intel VT-X can't work together. So I proceeded to uninstall and disable everything related to WSL2 but the problem persists.  I have Intel VT-X enabled from BIOS, and I have Hyper-V disabled.

[Windows Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3tKV.jpg)

Comment: “I read that WSL2 and Intel VT-X can't work together.” Hardware virtualization is required for WSL2. Whatever you read was absolutely false. I can tell by the screenshot you don’t have the required optional features enabled. Considering it’s impossible to enable Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home you were to aggressive in disabling Windows features. Enable the required features for WSL2 but DO NOT enable WSL2 (since you want to use VMWare)

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, so what should I enable for the EVE-NG virtual machine to work properly in VMWare? I'm confused

Comment: Enable both of those features you circled for starters and uninstall any and all software that uses hardware virtualization except for VMWare Player

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall Hyper-V, Windows Subsystem For Linux and Virtual Machine Platform and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Hypervisor. Open CMD as admin.
TO DISABLE

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

If you want to enable it back just type:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`